# EntityFramework 6 - Get DbSet<> without registering model in context

Tags: c#, entity-framework

In Linq-to-sql i am able to get a table without registering model in the context.
However, in EF i get the `The entity type A is not part of the model for the current context.` error.

Below is the code listing:

```
class Program
  {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      const string constr = @"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;Initial Catalog=Test";

      var ctx = new MyContext(constr);
      var table = ctx.GetTable<A>();

      var a = table.FirstOrDefault();

      var efCtx = new EfContext(constr);
      var set = efCtx.Set<A>();
      var b = set.FirstOrDefault();
    }
  }

  [System.Data.Linq.Mapping.Table]
  class A
  {
    [System.Data.Linq.Mapping.Column]
    [Key]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    [System.Data.Linq.Mapping.Column]
    public string B { get; set; }
  }

  class EfContext : DbContext
  {
    public EfContext(string con)
      : base(con)
    {
    }
  }

  class MyContext : DataContext
  {
    public MyContext(string fileOrServerOrConnection)
      : base(fileOrServerOrConnection)
    {
    }
  }
```

The exception is thrown on this line `var set = efCtx.Set<A>();`

Is it possible to use EF the same way as linq-to-sql?

Comment: You can use SqlQuery<T> to get any object back from raw SQL - is that  what you are after?

Comment: The short answer is no, you can't use EF the same way. But you already know that from the exception :)